# DataFolder not found in the UI

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

1. I created a DataFolder of ContentType dataextension through SOAP API.
2. It was successfully created and I was also able to create a Data Extension with the ID of the data folder created in step 1
3. I am able to normal operations on the data extension.

However I am not able to see the data extension or the folder in the Marketing Cloud UI. If I create a data extension without mentioning CategoryID I am able to see the data extension in the UI at root level.

Where can I find this data extension in the UI?

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide parent folder ID.

"datafolder.ParentFolder.ID"

You can check those in UI by "right clicking" a folder and inspecting one (Web-dev tools in Google Chrome for instance)

[image]